# SQL error or missing database / OneToMany SQLIte-Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with the relationship oneToMany. I created tables in SQLite DB, this is my tables:
[image]

My CategoryModel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class CategoryModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String category_name;
    private String category_description;
    private String image_path;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<ProductModel> category;
```

My ProducCategory:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product_Category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class ProductModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long product_id;
    private Long category_id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int numberOfProduct;
    private String image;
    private int price;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
    private CategoryModel category;
```

I can get data from the `Category` table well but when I call data from the Product_Category table I have the error:

```
SQL error or missing database (no such column: productmod0_.country_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`country_id` does not exist anywhere in your tables.

What you want is :  `@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)`

Comment: Now I have this error: `[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: productmod0_.id)`

Comment: `@Column(name = "id")` in JPA but `product_id` in database. Isn't all this very obvious?